# Changing name in Header in Openerp?

Tags: header

I want to change Header name as a clients in openerp. I am using python and xml. see my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: pls anyone tell answer for this. If you don't understand this question, tell me. i will explain clearly

Comment: can you provide your xml file or tag where tree view, action are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to edit the XML for the action. Activate developer mode by going to help > About openERP > click active developer mode.

That will let you see the developer information. Then click edit action, and change the name of the action to what you want.

Comment: This is a temporary solution. When you upgrade your database with that module. Your changes will be disappear. Anyway good.