# Increment sequence when I click discard button

Tags: python, odoo, sequence

I am working in openerp using python and xml:

I am trying to add sequence in my client form. i have added successfully. But count is Increasing by 1 when i click save and discard button. i want to increament by 1 while save the record only.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="seq_type_master_item" model="ir.sequence.type">
            <field name="name">Master item</field>
            <field name="code">master.item</field>
        </record>

        <record id="seq_master_item" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Master item</field>
            <field name="code">master.item</field>
            <field name="prefix">CS</field>
            <field name="padding">3</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

python:

```
_defaults = {
  'client_id': lambda self,cr,uid,context: self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'master.item')
 }

'client_id':fields.char(' ',size=64)
```

Comment: Have you marked your column field as **readonly** ? Please post the column section in your question.

Comment: i added column. pls see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

In your **view.xml** file change this

```
<field name="clien_id" readonly="1"/>
```

Comment: if i put readonly, it generates two id at the same time. example:assume id is c01 while click create button and i get c02 after i saved record.

Comment: that because of you called sequence by default. See your _defaults in .py file

Comment: as per my advice call sequence in create method. So you need to override create method of that object.

Comment: you can search it core module like in purchase.py file or sale.py file. Just search "def create" method. you can get idea.

Comment: yes i have got proper sequence in my by this way form Thank you very much.

Comment: def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context={}):
    next_seq = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'master.lead')
    vals['lead_id'] = next_seq
    res = super(crm_lead, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
    return res

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821094/changing-name-in-header-in-openerp. answer for this